# iOS: My app crashed in iPhone when i am installing from test fairy but in iPad it's working fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, testfairy

I am installing my App from test fairy to iPhone it's crashed but in iPad it's working fine. And it working fine in debugging mode(Cable connect with xcode), Unable to find the Crashing Scenario.. Please help me for find the Issue.
Here I have Give the Crash report and Screenshot.

> NSInvalidArgumentException: Cannot create task from nil request.

[image]

Comment: Which build scheme you are using for debugging with cable and TestFairy?

Comment: Same build the build no 2, Same in iPad also but it working fine.

Comment: Show us the code where your `EnrichedValues` class makes HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are making any network request but this request object `(NSURLRequest)` is nil. Can you put any code of `loadViewIfRequired` to review the crash?

Comment: Yes, it can works on iPad but with added log is imposible to add information about your crash. If you add a code example I can check it and look for any problems.